# Send from Email with avatar attached

Tags: gmail

I have multiple E-Mail addresses which I have added to Gmail so that I send mail with that address.

I am wondering if it is possible to connect these email addresses to separate avatars, without having to create a Google+ profile for them.

I could then have my company logo appear next to my email whenever someone reads my mail in Gmail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create individual signatures (each having seperate avatars) in Gmail. This will enable you to insert the signatures for incoming and outgoing e-mails. It isn't done automatically however...

See following reference about creating multiple signatures: [multiple signatures](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=176652).